# draw a circuit with circular loop

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to add a loop as in the picture. The MWE below is what I have tried.
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document} 
\begin{circuitikz}
     \draw (0,0) to[sV] (3,0);
     \draw(3,0) to [full diode] (4,0);
     \draw(4,0)--(5,0);
     \draw(5,0)--(5,-2);
     \draw(5,-2)--(4,-2);
     \draw(4,-2) to[cute inductor] (1,-2); 
     \draw(0,0)--(0,-2)--(1,-2);
     \draw(3.5,0) circle(17pt);
     \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
   \draw (0,0) to[sV] (3,0);
   \draw(3,0) to [full diode] (4,0);
   \draw(4,0)--(5,0);
   \draw(5,0)--(5,-2);
   \draw(5,-2)--(4,-2);
   \draw(4,-2) to[cute inductor] (1,-2);
   \draw(0,0)--(0,-2)--(1,-2);
   \draw(3.5,0) circle(17pt);
   %
   \draw[xshift = 2.6cm, yshift = -3.5cm] (-0.6, 0) -- ++(0, 0.5) -- ++(0.4, 0)
   -- ++(0, 0.5) arc (250 : -70 : 0.3cm and 0.8cm) -- ++(0, -0.5) -- ++(0.4, 0)
   -- ++(0, -0.5) -- ++(-0.4, 0) arc (0 : 180 : 0.1cm) -- cycle (-0.1, 0) circle (0.2cm);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Which part and key words of tikz manual can I read for such code by caverac?

Comment: @Thumbolt Section 2 `Tutorial: A Picture for Karl’s Students` should be enough to draw it